# How does the ft2232h read/write work in cpu-style FIFO interface mode?

Tags: communication, ftdi

I'm thinking of making the following circuitry:
PC <-> Ft2232h <-> MCU
(I'm using the MCU just for an initial test to see if I can get the ft2232 working. An FPGA will be used later)

Have I understood the following read/write procedures correctly?
In order to read from the MCU to the PC:
 1. Set the pins (on my MCU) connected to D7-D0 (channel A or B), to the required logic level representing the data to be read.
 2. Set CS# = 0, A0 = 0.
 3. Toggle RD# from high to low and then high again.

In order to write to the MCU from the PC:
 1. Set CS# = 0, A0 = 0.
 2. Toggle WR# from high to low and then high again.
 3. Read from the pins (on my MCU) connected to D7-D0 (channel A or B)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the functions of `RD#` and `WR#` backwards. As shown on page 40 of the [datasheet](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/ICs/DS_FT2232H.pdf), `RD#` is used to transfer data from the FT2232H to the MCU (which is "writing" from the host PC's point of view), and `WR#` is used to transfer data from the MCU to the FT2232H, from where it can be read by the host PC.

Answer (score 0):

two issue:
1. A0 need high-low transform, so that data will load to buffer and then from buffer output to IO pin. See datasheet Page 40, table 4.7.

2. read=>  data from FT2232H output; write=> data input to FT2232;